# The RequireJS order plugin and Dojo 1.7.1

Tags: javascript, dojo, requirejs, js-amd

I am upgrading a project from Dojo 1.6.1 using AMD and RequireJS to Dojo 1.7.1 with its new AMD loader. I have to deal with old JavaScript files, not written as AMD modules, and have to load them in the correct order.

Before I used the RequireJS order plugin, but it does not seem to work with Dojo AMD Loader. I can not find anything about it in the loader documentation or the Dojo Build System documentation.

Any thoughts about this? If there is no order plugin, how should I handle plain JavaScript files together with Dojo 1.7? Do I need to handle them separately, or are there functionality for this in the loader or build system?

Comment: Are you talking about module-less files or old style synchronous modules?

Comment: Just ordinary JavaScript files, like jQuery (not used as an AMD module), written in whatever style they may be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just learning about this myself, but the documentation I found refers to [Generic Script Injection](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/loader/amd.html#generic-script-injection)

Load your generic scripts as described in the docs, while specifying {async: 0}  as a configuration option for require(). This, to my understanding, does load the scripts in the order that you specify in the the second parameter (the array containing the script filenames/paths)

My example:

```
require({async:0},['test1.js','test2.js','test3.js'],function(){
    //do stuff with reference to loaded scripts

});
```

My local tests show if I change config to {async: 1} the scripts load in a different order to what I specified. So far I haven't tracked this down in the dojo loader code, but it seems to make sense, and work, and isn't a hack.

Comment: I'm acceptiong this answer, because it works! I created a "dependency module" this way: `define(["require"], function(require){ require({async:0}, [ "script1.js", "script2.js", "script3.js" ]); });`. I think it's an ok solution. Thanks!

Comment: One caveat, though. I have not investigated it further, but it seems (at least when you load the scripts in a separate module as mentioned above) the scripts are loaded in a different scope than if loaded via a conventional script tag. For example, I had to replace `var uglyGlobal = true` with `window.uglyGlobal = true`.

Comment: The script injection method for `{async:1}` config loads the scripts using an injected `<script>` tag into the dom (you can see them in the webkit or firebug inspector), so vars in the loaded scripts are available as globals. I guess `{async:0}` loads scripts an evals them within their own scope? Have you tried defining your dependency module by embedding require calls? something like: `define(["require"], function(require{require(['test1.js'],function({require(['test2.js'],function({require(['test3.js'],function(){})})});});` May load them in the order you define?

Comment: the above example loads as `{async:1}`  and appears to work for me, although I've not tested thoroughly

Comment: Hmmm, that's an interesting idea. Maybe one could write a monad to handle the nesting, and then be able to write something like `requireChain("test1.js").then("test2.js").then("test3.js")`.

Comment: Again, I'm not very familiar with it, just learning myself, but maybe to do that you could try looking at the [Dojo AMD plugins](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/loader/amd.html#plugins) - they require a load object and with a callback property that could be used to get your scripts into order.

Comment: @JohanJonasson, take care with your dependency module. It creates a race condition as your module might return before the require statement has been completed. Return a Deferred and check for it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to propose another approach for such a dependency module as mentioned in the comments above. The problem is that `define` doesn't accept an `async` parameter. Using a simple `require` inside the `define` function introduces a race condition because the code of the required modules is not executed yet.

Example (**WRONG**):
oldCode.js

```
window.foo = function(){};
```

legacyWrapper.js

```
define(["require"],function(require){
    require({async:0},["./oldCode"]);
})
```

code.js

```
define(["./legacyWrapper"],function(){
    window.foo(); //throws exception, foo has not been loaded yet.
})
```

([jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tHPxN/1/))

**However, there is a solution to this problem.** You need to return a [Deferred](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/promises/) that gets resolved as soon as all modules are loaded. The following example loads a,b,c,d in order.

```
define(["require","dojo/Deferred"],function(require,Deferred){
    var def = new Deferred();
    require({async:0},
            ["./moduleA",
             "./moduleB",
             "./moduleC",
             "./moduleD"],
             function(){
        def.resolve();
    });
    return def;
})
```

To access properties defined in moduleA, you can now use

```
require(["legacyDeps"],function(legacyDeps){
    legacyDeps.then(function(){
        //It's save to assume that all legacy modules have been loaded here.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think plugins are generally compatible across AMD loaders.  It's not optimal, but you can probably use dojo/text! with an eval.  That would inline the content at buildtime.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `define([ "text!myScript", "text!myScript2" ], function(s, s2){  eval(s); eval(s2) })`

Comment: It works, and I'm using it in a doh test, but I'm reluctant to mark it as the accepted answer, it's a hack =)